# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in office web add-in

Tags: javascript, ajax, office-addins

I am trying to call the POST REST API from the office outlook web add-in using ajax calls, for target url Configured the app domains in the manifest.xml file but I am facing same CORS issue.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https:' from origin 'https:' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I couldn't find the reason and what is wrong with it.

MessageRead.js code

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "<target url>",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            crossDomain: true,
            headers:
            {
                'X-Database': 'aln_template',
            },
                          data: {
                //id: "1598521065618",
                id: (new Date()).getTime(),
                method: "execute",
                params: params
            },
            success: function (data1) {
     }
});
```

Comment: I given Allow-Origin as wildcard, but still it's not working.

Comment: What is the url you are posing?

Comment: I didn't find any solution from provided links

Answer (score 0):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header, not a request header. You can’t send that particular header with your post request, which is why it’s being rejected.

Comment: Nick Dawes, if I remove Access-Control-Allow-Origin from request header I am getting another CORS error,
 
Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.